# Как в StoryBoard перейти к другой сцене без нажатия кнопки?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Собственно говоря - нужно чтобы переход произошел при достижении определенных порогов.
То есть например Х стал больше 100 - и реализовался `segue`.
Ну и если Х еще меньше 100 - то `segue` не реализуется.

Когда у меня есть некая кнопка - от которой идет segue и есть `segue identifier` - то здесь  я могу реализовать это через `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`:

Как быть?

Comment: очевидно, что нужно отслеживать изменение икса и по условию выполнять действие перехода. Не понятно, что такое "еще" в "Ну и если Х еще меньше 100". Само условие x < 100 подразумевает что меньшЕе оно не станет, оно просто меньше.

Comment: ну то есть объясню - чтобы было понятно на какой я сейчас стадии.

все переходы в StoryBoard у меня идут через нажатия кнопок.

то есть даже если кнопка не нажимается мной в какой-то период, то я могу все равно сделать переход через perform... посредством указания segue identifier.

а как мне сделать perform... если у меня не назначен segue identifier - так как собственно нет кнопки  - нет действия - нет перехода - нет идентификатора перехода - а без него perform сделать не могу

Comment: может быть можно сделать такой переход с использованием StoryboardID?

Comment: Но ведь NavigationController то есть? Значит в него можно поместить нужный в данный момент контроллер. Этот контроллер можно инициализировать используя StoryBoard (если сильно нужно  через SB используя его ID), либо обычным способом.

Comment: дадада! я понял, прошу конкретики - как именно инициализировать контроллер используя StoryboardID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот как то так:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"StoryboardName" bundle: nil];
MyViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyControllerID"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: vc animated: YES];
```

Comment: глубочайше благодарю )))